# What governs the use of "и" in statements containing the conjunction "хотя"?

Tags: particles

I recently got the following sentence from Duolingo: "хотя они все и великие писатели, вашa ученицa их не знает". Being a beginner, I'm confused by the 'и', which I'm interpreting as 'and' — clearly incorrectly. What role does the 'и' play here? If it's omitted (i.e. "хотя все и они великие писатели..."), how does the meaning change?

Comment: That's a strange phrase, are you sure you quote it correctly? "И хотя все они великие писатели..." or "хотя все они и великие писатели..." makes way more sense.

Comment: @Petr: I copied the text incorrectly. The question has been edited to reflect the actual wording.

Comment: Petr, absolutely nothing is a "strange" here. Just a colloquial intensification and variations.

Comment: John Källén, it's absolutely right and so and so.

Comment: It means "even though" , A translation: "Even though these are great writers, your pupil does not know them".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is incorrect and does not make sense as quoted. It probably was intended to be «хотя все они и великие писатели, вашa ученицa их не знает». In that case "и" emphasizes the conditional conjunction "хотя", something like: "Even though they are [obviously] famous writers, your student does not know them".

One might just as well say «хотя все они великие писатели...», omitting "и", but that would sound a bit "flat".

Also, though this may be subjective, the "и" seems to change the stress pattern of the sentence: «хотя все они великие **писатели**, вашa ученицa...» vs. «хотя все они и **великие** писатели, вашa ученицa...».

Comment: My mistake; I'll correct the wording

Comment: could you augment your answer with English translations to provide the contrast between the 'и'- and 'и'-less sentence?

Comment: I attempted to indicate that by the optionality of "[obviously]".

Answer (score 8):

It means "even though all of them are great writers, your student doesn't know them".

In Russian, *и*, among other things, means "even".

It can be used in this sense as a standalone word:

> - Я его и знать не хочу! Я буду мужа любить. // I don't even want to be anywhere near him (*literally, "I don't even want to know him"*). I will love my husband.
> - Я его и не видел с тех пор. // I haven't even seem him since.
> - Бойся данайцев и дары приносящих // [Beware of Greeks, even bearing gifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeo_Danaos_et_dona_ferentes)

, but more often, it is used as a part the set phrases *хотя и* "even though" or *даже и* "even".

*Хотя и* can be split, which is something that you are seeing in your example.

*Хотя* should precede the subject or the subject phrase, and the *и* should precede the predicate.

In your case, *все они* is the subject phrase and *великие писатели* is the predicate phrase, so it should be *хотя все они и великие писатели*

*Хотя* can be used without *и*, sometimes for stylistic reasons: in sylleptic constructs (where some parts of the sentence are omitted to avoid repetition); when *хотя* and *и* would end up too far apart from each other; when the predicate phrase starts with a dependent word; and in many other cases.

> Однажды родители привели своего сына к колдуну ― мальчик очень плохо учился, хотя был неглуп.

Here, you can also use *хотя и был неглуп*

> Хотя Чуриков, сидя в президиуме напротив зала, упорно называл совещание "круглым столом", противоречие заключалось не только в меблировке.

Here, *упорно* modifies the verb *называл*, so it's a dependent word within the predicate phrase. Hence, *и* doesn't fit here. If we omitted the word *упорно* or moved out after *называл*, we could have added *и* before *называл*.

> В целом врачи сработали оперативно, хотя элементы хаоса наблюдались и здесь.

Putting *и* before *наблюдались* would have resulted in duplication of *и*, which would be stylistically bad.

Comment: Хотя этот ответ и верен, I think the essence of the question was - what is the difference between "хотя" and "хотя и"?

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, the difference is one of **emphasis**.

When "и" plays the part of a conjunction, it's translated as "and".

But here, it's a **particle** translated as **"even"** and it adds an **additional stress** to the fact stated after хотя.

Comment: How does хоть и fit in here. Is it exactly the same as хотя и, or does it carry a different or additional nuance?

Comment: Хоть и is a colloquial variant of neutral  хотя и

Comment: Wow! And here I though it was more bookish. Thank you 

Answer (score -1):

Хотя is used in complex sentences. It means "even through", "despite this"

It can be replaced with "Несмотря на ..."